# A simple four line Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Tirelessly I hammer away
>   yet over time my work frays
>   Making things both new and old
>   but what I make one cannot hold

Who or What am I?

Edit:

> Changed last line to rhyme better, credit to Pugmonkey

Comment: The "be hold" instead of "be held" is just for the rhyme it's not a hint

Comment: How about "cannot be hold" -> "I cannot hold"?

Comment: It would be confusing that only you cannot hold that or nobody can.@JoonasIlmavirta

Comment: Or "but what I make one cannot hold".  It keeps the rhyme and doesn't create unintended ambiguity.

Comment: "my work frays" -> "my work doth fray"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you are a

> Piano

Tirelessly I hammer away

> A piano is an instrument in which the strings are struck by hammers.

yet over time my work frays

> Piano wire is strong but the strings do wear (and fray) over time from repeated hammering.

Making things both new and old

> A piano can be used to create new music or reproduce songs written by others.

but what I make cannot be hold

> Music cannot be held.

Comment: All Lines correct, well done

Answer (score 19):

More of a joke:

That's:

> me

Tirelessly I hammer away

> I'm a software developer and I've been hammering away on the keyboard for ages.

yet over time my work frays

> But the software I write tends to get old and obsolete

Making things both new and old

> I write new code and I fix old code

but what I make cannot be hold

> You can't really hold a piece of software.

Comment: LOL, I feel your pain. Monday blues? Or everyday blues? ☺

Comment: @Phylyp After 30 years in the trade it tends to be a constant blues.

Comment: Haha great answer, sadly not the one I was looking for

Comment: 'hammering away on the keyboard for ages' :) :) +1

Answer (score 6):

I think you may be

> Water.

Tirelessly I hammer away

> Rivers/Rain/Glaciers/etc. have shaping the landscape for decades, *maybe longer*.

yet over time my work frays

> The work of water creating canyons, glaciers digging out lakes, soil erosion, and even [waves](http://alanhamr.weebly.com/uploads/1/8/6/0/18607614/4753647_orig.jpg)

Making things both new and old

> From [A single drop of rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Water_and_soil_splashed_by_the_impact_of_a_single_raindrop.jpg) causing a divot to the Colorado River's 5 million-year carving out of the Grand Canyon.

but what I make cannot be hold

> These things, like a hole, are the absence of something, which cannot be physically be held.

Answer (score 4):

I think it might be a

> woodpecker

Tirelessly I hammer away

> a woodpecker is known for this fast pecking

yet over time my work frays

> since a tree will grow and change or simply die, the work done by the woodpacker will disappear over time.

Making things both new and old

> i am unsure about how this third line would fit, so maybe i am on the wrong track.

but what I make cannot be hold

> what he makes are holes, wich you can not hold.

Answer (score 4):

**You could be a**

> **computer keyboard.**

Tirelessly I hammer away

> As keys are struck, they hammer on the mechanical switches or rubber domes beneath them.

yet over time my work frays

> The most well-constructed keyboards will wear out eventually with regular use. Even classics like the IBM Model M!

Making things both new and old

> Keyboards can be used to make all manner of things -- stories, poetry, software, a series of game inputs. They can transcribe or copy old things, or they can be used to write new things.

but what I make one cannot hold

> Computer documents are digital, and can't be held in the conventional sense. Well, unless you print the documents out.

Answer (score 1):

**I think it's**

> **a pocket/wrist-watch (mechanical analog)**

Tirelessly I hammer away

> The hammer is a part of a watch mechanism.

yet over time my work frays

> Watches wind down over time and need to be rewound.

Making things both new and old

> Kind of a pun on the fact that watches "make time" by marking the seconds and minutes of a day.

but what I make one cannot hold

> Time is intangible.